# The superclass 'Bloc<Event, State>' doesn't have a zero argument constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

[image]

1. If I create a constructor to call super, I have to pass an argument to the BlocProvider's create property too. I don't know how to handle this.

   CounterBloc(CounterState initialState) : super(initialState);
2. If the below code is necessary for the bloc?

   @override
   CounterState get initialState => ShowCounterState(counterValue);

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't override `initialState`. If you'd like to specify the initial state in your `Bloc` class while having a zero-argument constructor, constructor, then do something like this:

```
CounterBloc() : super(ShowCounterState(0));
```

Alternatively, use the constructor in your point #1, and pass the value when instantiating the Bloc, like so:

```
final yourBloc = CounterBloc(ShowCounterState(0));
```